# Installation of a Canon MF8380Cdw on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I am trying to install a Canon Color imageCLASS MF8380Cdw in a 64-bit installation of Ubuntu 14.04. I was able to [download the Linux drivers](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/imageclass_series/color_imageclass_mf8380cdw#DriversAndSoftware), but after running the `.deb` files and installing the printer through System Settings > Printers (just using the Add wizard), the printer shows up in the Printers pane, but printing to it fails with no error messages.

The printer has worked on this computer in the past, but had to be re-installed after a recent clean install of Ubuntu. I am not sure how to proceed from here, since I get no error messages either on the computer or on the printer.

I read [a similar posting](/q/251015), but since Canon provided Linux drivers, I just used them as-is - so I don't think it is relevant to my situation.

Comment: Additional information: when I print a Test page from the Printer application, the job briefly appears in the print queue, then goes away as though it was successfully delivered to the printer.  The print queue is then empty.  But no print jobs or errors appear on the printer.

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure why, but the printer is now working.  the only change of any consequence that I am aware of is changing a Printer setting (Report/Communication Management/Auto)

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem on Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 LTS, and fixed it by installing the following packages. Yes, some of these are 32-bit packages on a 64-bit system.

```
sudo apt-get install libglade2-0 libstdc++6:i386 libxml2:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libbeecrypt7:i386 libbeecrypt-dev:i386
```

These packages are installed if you run the `install.sh` script included in the driver download.